# Res header contaisn set Cookie but browser isn't storing it

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, express-session

I'm using express-session to store session cookie. I can see Set-Cookie connect.ssid under the response header but for some reason it is not getting stored in the cookie.

[image: Respnse header]

I'm wondering if this is a CORS issue, my app file looks like this. Should I change something here to make it work.

```
const session = require('express-session');
const config = require('config');
var MemoryStore = require('memorystore')(session);

module.exports = function (app) {
    // app.use(
    //     session({
    //         secret: 'key sign',
    //         resave: false,
    //         saveUninitialized: false
    //     })
    // );
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors({ credentials: true }));
    enter code here
    app.set('trust proxy', 1);
    app.use(
        session({
            saveUninitialized: false,
            cookie: { maxAge: 86400000 },
            store: new MemoryStore({
                checkPeriod: 86400000
            }),
            resave: false,
            cookie: { secure: false },
            secret: config.get('sessionStorage')
        })
    );
  
    app.use('/api/users', users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed this.

1. Add SSL to both frontend and backend.
2. If it is self-signed, ensure browser trust it. For example, if you're using mac, go to keychain, select specific certificate and select always trust option.
3. Restart the system. Only then SSL will be properly set otherwise there would still be insecure badge in the navigations.